# Is there any memcached equivalent in php?

Tags: php, caching, memcached

In my website , i want to show some data which will be displayed from the db for the whole day .

For example, if i have a portion like ' Picture of the day', then i will pick a random picture from the db and display them on the page.

So i dont want the query to be executed for every request . so i decided to use memcached to cache query results for a particular time(may be for 24  hrs) ..

All worked in localhost but my hosting provider does not have them.. So i have to use some different concepts to accomplish this.

Is there any equivalent for memcache in php?

Comment: If the don't allow you to use memcache, do they have APC enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a file for caching, and a `filemtime()` call to see whether the pick needs to be refereshed. Or a database record containing the pick, and the date it was made.

Both methods would work fine performance-wise for this task - memcache sounds like a bit of overkill for it (although it's obviously convenient to use when it's available)

Comment: That would be nice. But for example if my needs are bigger, like i want to give search results for queries and my db server will be pinged with multiple queries but yields same results for same queries. If the top most searched items are repeatedly searched, then if i have any cache then it would improve the performance. For a situation where data need to be cached are large, what would be better option? I know that for my earlier question , i got answer, but for situation for this, i want to know for future reference :)

Comment: @kvijayhari mmm, stuff like that can always be also cached in files or a database, but obviously that's slower than memcache which might hurt for bigger things. If your needs are that complex, you might be better off with a provider who has memcache enabled? Might save you a lot of rewriting.

Answer (score 2):

Though APC cache (https://www.php.net/apc) is not meant for this, it might work for you if it is enabled by your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

You should save it as a file. A Cache is not a storage and you should always expect, that a cache gets cleared even if the timeout has not expired yet.

However, you dont need to save the file as (e.g.) "pictoreOfTheDay.jpg". You must have the pictures saved somewhere anyway, so you will only need to save the filename of one is this.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a memcache extension:  http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

Comment: If he cannot install Memcache on the server how is he going to install a PHP extension? Even if he could what use would it be? There would be no Memcache server to connect to.

Comment: he asked if there was an equivalent.  There's an extension.  That's all I was pointing out.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on shared hosting and can't install memcached, I think your only other option is to store it in your database.

- Save the cached results as a flat file, which would be relatively slow.
- You could configure your mysql server to run an in memory database to get better performance.
- Run a sqlite instance.

It all depends on which options are available on your hosting.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what does your hosting provider support.

As a last resort you can always write the content in a file on disk and either open/read/close the file out or use fpassthru() to output the file directly

Answer (score 0):

You can use file cache for this. An example tutorial http://fclose.net/php-file-cache-sinifi